# SignalR: la conexión no se ha inicializado por completo. Utilice .start (). Done () o .start (). Fail () después de que la conexión haya comenzado

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp, signalr

Tratando de replicar un ejemplo que encontré en internet el cual usa **SignalR** y **Angular**, en donde esta desarrollado de manera local, lo cual permite por medio de un click hacer una petición y traer un saludo mas la fecha del servidor, pero al tratar de hacerlo usando un servidor en la nube, no funciona, solo intento cambiar donde se estable la conexión, pero no he podido lograrlo.

Aquí dejo el [enlace del ejemplo](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com.co/2013/05/HookingUpAspNetSignalRWithAngularJS.html), hay que hacerle unas modificaciones breves al codigo ya que algunas cosas son obsoletas, pero en si es como una o dos lineas de código del lado del servidor.

Este es mi código:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.value('$', $);

app.factory('signalRSvc', function ($, $rootScope) {
    return {
        proxy: null,
        initialize: function (acceptGreetCallback) {           

            //Getting the connection object
            connection = $.hubConnection('http://host:puerto');         

            //Creating proxy
            this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('HelloWorldHub');

            //Starting connection
            connection.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
                alert("funciono");
            });

            connection.start({ jsonp: true }).fail(function () {
                alert("fallo");
            });

            //connection.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
            //    console.log("connection started!");
            //});  


            //Attaching a callback to handle acceptGreet client call
            this.proxy.on('acceptGreet', function (message) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    acceptGreetCallback(message);
                });
            });
        },
        sendRequest: function (callback) {
            //Invoking greetAll method defined in hub
            this.proxy.invoke('greetAll');
        }
    }
});

app.controller('SignalRAngularCtrl', function ($scope, signalRSvc) {

    $scope.text = "";

    $scope.greetAll = function () {
        signalRSvc.sendRequest();
    }

    updateGreetingMessage = function (text) {
        $scope.text = text;
    }

    signalRSvc.initialize(updateGreetingMessage);

});
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no es un problema de CORS?

Comment: Pues según leo por aquí al parecer si es eso, por que en esta pregunta que respondió la misma persona que la hizo, recomendó usar **CORS**, en vez de **jsonp**, [enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30844546/4756890)

Comment: Te recomendaría mirar el código fuente del signal R.

Comment: ok, le echare un ojo

Comment: qué fue hermano? lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: @fredyfx pues si, pero igual por ahora no lo vamos a usar, por que depende de muchas cosas.

Comment: Y si agregas la respuesta :D

Comment: @fredyfx perdon, del servidor y con jquery puro lo hicimos, pero no pude hacerlo funcionar ocn angular, por que no segui en eso por que luego toco esperar algo en la universidad y me ocupe en el libro, pero debemos sentarnos a poner eso

Comment: ya listo hermano, cuando tengas chance :D

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Signal R client esta instalado de lado del cliente  y signal r del lado del backend ?? .  Favor , ponga el código del Hub del Backend.

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de tu lenguaje Backend o si puedes agrear una regla a tu servidor en la configuración de apache, agrega esta regla o cabecera:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

Por reglas de CORS, se impide devolver respuestas a  peticiones externas mediantes conexiones  XMLHttpRequest o AJAX